# Summ field value from all records

Tags: mysql, sum

Hy. How can I setup the query if i would sum all values stored in a field?
Now I have that query:

```
"SELECT views FROM visitors WHERE visited_user = '123'"
```

And i have this records stored:

```
id    visitor   visited_user    views
-------------------------------------
1     555       123             15
2     666       123             23
3     777       123             45
-------------------------------------
total                           83
```

Comment: What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Are you looking for [WITH ROLLUP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-modifiers.html)?

Comment: I need just the total so the SUM(views) it does ;) thank you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [sum() function](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp):

```
SELECT SUM(views) 
FROM   visitors 
WHERE  visited_user = '123'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(views) FROM visitors WHERE visited_user = '123'
```